# Git Equivalent of Visual SourceSafe Keyword Expansion $History

Tags: git, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

We have recently moved from using Visual SourceSafe for source control to using Git.

While SourceSafe has justifiably had a lot of criticism it has one feature which was quite useful: [Keyword Expansion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d826hy97%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Keyword tags could be added to source files.  When SourceSafe checked in a file it would read the keywords and add informational comments to the head of the file.

The SourceSafe keyword we found most useful is $History: $.  When the file is checked in the checkin comment is added as a comment to the head of the file.  We find these checkin comments particularly useful in SQL scripts used to update objects such as stored procedures in a database.

Does Git have any equivalent method of inserting metadata comments into source files during commit?

Comment: People should listen to what Peter says. I hear he's a smart guy.

Comment: The Smudge/Clean Filters in one of the answers in the x-ref'd question look like what you want, more or less.  Actually, I'm very far from convinced that the checkin comments are really useful; that information is in the repository and best left there.  But version identification, etc — that I think is useful.  It means you can have a better chance of identifying where a copy of a file came from even when it is detached from the rest of the code shipped from a repository.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: You're right, mostly we use the history just to tell which version a file is.  Not so important for compiled code but very useful for "interpreted" code like scripts to update SQL objects.